# Find cordinate of a vector in triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, triangles

So, the task goes like this: $A(0,1,0), B(3,1,2), C(2,0,1)$ are cordinates of a triangle $ABC$. Point $D$ is a height drawn from point $A$ , and point $E$ is a middle of side $BC$. Find cordinates of vector $ \overrightarrow{DE} $

I can find cordinates of $ \overrightarrow{BC} $, so we get  $\overrightarrow{BC}(-1,-1,-1)$ and cordinate of point $E$ should be $E(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$

My idea is next: to make a equation of a slope on $BC$ side and after that height from point $A$ should cut that slope and create point $D$ there.

Equation of a slope should be : $\frac{x-3}{-1} = \frac{y-1}{-1} = \frac{z-2}{-1} $

Am I doing this right? If I am what should I do next?

Is it possible to do this without using a slope? I mean if I calculate $DC$ so I should get $DE= DC-EC$. My guess here should be to check angle of point $C$ and I should find $|DE|$, but how can I determinante components of this vector?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "Point $D$ is a height drawn from point $A$"?

Comment: Fix coordinates of $E.$ What you have written is half of the vector $\vec {BC},$.

Comment: A line drawn from point $A$ on $BC$ side which creates angle of $90$ degree(right angle)

Comment: I still do not understand. A diagram may be useful!

Comment: Added diagram on edit, and should cordinates of $E$ be as I said or $\frac{5}{2},\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E$ is a midpoint of $BC$ then $$E = {1\over 2}(B+C) = ({5\over 2},{1\over 2},{3\over 2})$$

If $D(x,y,z)$ on $BC$ then $$ D = tB+(1-t)C = (3t,t,2t)+(2-2t,0,1-t)= (2+t,t,1+t)$$

and since $AD\bot BC$ $$(x,y-1,z)\cdot (1,1,1)=0\implies x+y+z =1$$

so $$ 2+t+t+1+t=1\implies t=-2/3\implies D({4\over 3},-{2\over 3},{1\over 3})$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you mind clarify my how do you get this formula $D = tB+(1-t)C$ and after that you do you get $(x,y-1,z)$

Comment: It is vector equation of the line.

Comment: $AD = D-A = (x,y,z)-(0,1,0) = (x,y-1,z)$

Comment: I see now, could you tell me how do you get this formula: $D=tB+(1-t)C$ I never came across of this.

Comment: $BD = t \cdot BC$